# Carregar imagem redimensionada no wordpress

Tags: php, imagem, resize

Boa noite. Estou tentando carregar apenas as "miniaturas" das imagens na minha página customizada, porém o site carrega a imagem original e redimensiona sobre ela. Isso pesa o carregamento do meu site.

Meu código:

```
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <div class="row" id="products">
        <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 product" alt="<?php get_the_title() ?>" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>">
                <div class="change">
                    <i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">
                    <?php if(types_render_field('lancamento')=="Sim"): ?>
                    <div class="new <?php echo strtolower(types_render_field('tipo')) ?>">
                        <h1>Lançamento</h1>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="img top">
                        <img alt="<?php get_the_title() ?>" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>" src="<?php echo types_render_field("logo", array("width"=>"200","height"=>"200", "raw" => "true")); ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="img botton">
                        <img alt="<?php get_the_title() ?>" title="<?php get_the_title() ?>" src="<?php echo types_render_field("miniatura", array("size"=>"medium", "raw" => "true")); ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As divs "img top" e "img botton" e meus 2 testes nao funcionaram, são os blocos de carregamento da imagens, porem, o resultado nao é o que eu queria.

Imagens:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é seu caso, mas quando você faz upload das imagens via biblioteca de mídia do Wordpress, ele cria várias versões da imagem com dimensões diferentes no diretório `wp-content/uploads`.

Verifique se lá há estas variações. Daí, basta adaptar seu código para pegar a versão da imagem no tamanho que lhe for mais conveniente.

Comment: Estou tentando pegar imagem de resolução especifica na wp-content/uploads, porem sem sucesso. estou usando o types_render_field da Toolset. https://toolset.com/documentation/customizing-sites-using-php/functions/

Comment: Não seria mais simples você simplesmente juntar o prefixo da imagem com a dimensão dela? Por exemplo, se na pasta uploads tem a imagem "teste-150x150.jpg" não seria o caso de fazer apenas um `<?php echo $prefixo_da_imagem . "-150x150.jpg" ?>` ?